# Unable to get audio through hdmi on my raspberry pi zero

Tags: raspbian, audio, hdmi, pi-zero, omxplayer

I have already changed the gpu to run at 128, and have changed the hdmi_drive=1,2,3,4, and 5. I am unable to get audio from the test.h264 sample. I am trying to run video through omxplayer but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your TV might be connected to the Pi in DVI mode, hence the missing audio.

Try adding `hdmi_drive=2` ***and*** `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in your `/boot/config.txt` file.